# SQL Server add zero if there is length less than specific number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a column of numbers like `789`. I want to pad them with 0 to equal 9 digits. For example, `789` should be `789000000`

I have tried this code, but there are some numbers more than 3 digits and less than 3 digits.

```
UPDATE
   Table
SET
   MyCol = MyCol+'0000000'
WHERE
   LEN(MyCol) >9;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code does what you need, the bit you need is the REPLICATE section:

```
declare @var nvarchar(10);

set @var = '321'

select @var + REPLICATE('0',9-LEN(@var))
```

RESULT:

```
321000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question would be a better fit in stackoverflow, but I think you are after this:

```
UPDATE
   Table
SET
   MyCol = left(MyCol + '000000000', 9)
WHERE
   LEN(MyCol) < 9;
```